# web page is not the same on samsung smart tv

Tags: css, browser, samsung-smart-tv

I have a website that's working correct on `Chrome`, `Firefox`, `IE`. But it also needs to run on a samsung smart TV browser. And when I do that, my page doesn't look good. It seems to ignore the min-width and max-width, also the font is much smaller.

I'v googled and what I found is that it uses a `Tizen browser`. Is that possible?

I can't find anywhere why it's not working the same on `Chrome/Firefox`. 
Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix it?

EDIT:

Does it use `vw` or only `px`?

Comment: vw is supported https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/using-css3-units-support-low-and-high-density-screens

Comment: @Gerard so Tizen is the webbrowser that is being used on a samsung smart tv?

Comment: That's what it looks like https://www.tizen.org/blogs/myungjae/2017/samsung%E2%80%99s-third-tizen-.net-developer-preview-introduces-new-visual-studio-tools